# linking winform btn to different class

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a form holding a button that, when clicked, needs to perform the actions within another class.

for example,

the user clicks a btn thats says BookNow.

the coding within the btn needs to point to the BookNow class which has information for booking.

can anyone help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the `BookNow` class and call the function on it, from the button event handler.

```
public void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BookNow bn = new BookNow();

   // Call methods/properties on bn
}
```

I would avoid calling the button with the same name of the class, as you will run into namespace and naming conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for command design pattern

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx#_self1